# How to get id from selecting its value in spinner?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I want to get the id of the value selected in the spinner who's value is derived from Sqlite.

My table in Sqlite is

CITY_ID CITY_NAME

8                BOMBAY 
9                NEW DELHI 
10               MADRAS 
11               CALCUTTA 
12               BANGLORE 
13               AHMEDABAD 
14               JAIPUR 
15               CHANDIGARH 
16               SIMLA 
17               LUCKNOW 
18               PATNA 
19               BHOPAL 
20               NAGPUR

My Database Connector code is

```
public List<String> getCity(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  CITY_ID, CITY_NAME FROM city_list";

    Log.d("Destination Country Query", selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {                
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}
```

My implementation is

```
city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city);
loadCityData();

private void loadCityData() {

    DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> lables = db.getCity();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    city.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
```

Now by selecting the City in the spinner. I want to get the id from the SQlite table.

Can some one guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Dinesh

Comment: do you want to get selected value from spinner

Answer (score 1):

Adding value to Arraylist

```
    final ArrayList<Devstatus> statusList = new ArrayList<Devstatus>();

    Devstatus tempstatus = new Devstatus();
    tempstatus.setDevStatusName("BOMBAY ");
    tempstatus.setDevStatusValue("8");

    Devstatus tempstatus1 = new Devstatus();
    tempstatus1.setDevStatusName(" NEW DELHI ");
    tempstatus1.setDevStatusValue("9");

    statusList.add(tempstatus);
    statusList.add(tempstatus1);
```

Setting Addapter

```
    SpinnerAdapter stateAdaptor = new SpinnerAdapter(SettingActivity.this,statusList);
    status.setAdapter(stateAdaptor);
    status.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
            changeStatus(statusList.get(position));
            selected = statusList.get(position).getDevStatusName();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Spinner Adapter

```
 class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<Devstatus> statusList;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Devstatus> countryList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.statusList = countryList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.statusList.size();
    }

    public Devstatus getItem(int position) {
        return (Devstatus) this.statusList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (position);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        Devstatus tempState = (Devstatus) this.statusList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.state, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.adtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvstate);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder.adtitle.setText(tempState.getDevStatusName());
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView adtitle;

    }
}
```

Setter and getter

```
public class Devstatus 
{
private String devStatusName;
private String devStatusValue;


public String getDevStatusName() 
{
    return devStatusName;
}

public void setDevStatusName(String devStatusName) 
{
    this.devStatusName = devStatusName;
}

public String getDevStatusValue() 
{
    return devStatusValue;
}

public void setDevStatusValue(String devStatusValue) 
{
    this.devStatusValue = devStatusValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it. But it showing error. Can you please modify the above coding for my question connector and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `city name` as in `spinner` values. You will get its location, for `city id`, u could set values for `spinner` as `city_id`, then you can get its location and values,.. 
or you could use `city_nam`e and for its positions you are getting you could map its `city_id`values.

lets say for position `0` you will get `bombay`, then for position  `0` set `city_id` is `8`.
Like that.

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.i("cyberwalker", "item selected" + arg2);
            if (arg2 == 0) {
                city_id=8;
            } else if (arg2 == 1) {
                city_id=9;
            } else if (arg2 == 2) {
                city_id=10;
            }
                            ......

        }
```

Similarly, that code is not optimized.

Comment: Hi Cyberwalker,
Thanks for your tip. Can you please elaborate and give sample for me?